# I want to get individual access from flatlist when I press Accept or decline

Tags: react-native

need help if I press on accept button then simultaneously all requests getting accepted but I should be accepted as individually
I have given two screenshots of my output.

[image]

```
    import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    // import { StyleSheet, Linking, Text, View, Image, TextInput, Alert, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, ImageBackground, FlatList, SafeAreaView, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
    import { StatusBar, FlatList, Image, Animated, Text, View, Dimensions, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Easing, SafeAreaViewBase, SafeAreaView ,Button} from 'react-native';
    import {
        Avatar
    } from 'react-native-paper';
    import faker from 'faker';
    import { Card, CardTitle, CardContent, CardAction, CardButton, CardImage } from 'react-native-material-cards'
    import './global';
    
    
    export function notificationscreen({ navigation }) {
    
        faker.seed(10);
        const DATA = [...Array(30).keys()].map((_, i) => {
        return {
            key: faker.random.uuid(),
            image: `https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/${faker.helpers.randomize(['women', 'men'])}/${faker.random.number(60)}.jpg`,
            name:faker.name.findName(),
            fname: faker.name.firstName(),
            sname: faker.name.lastName(),
            // jobTitle: faker.name.jobTitle(),
            // email: faker.internet.email(),
        };
    });
    
    
    const SPACING = 20;
    const AVATAR_SIZE = 55;
    const [acpt, accept] = useState(false)
    const [rjct, reject] = useState(false)
    
    
    const stat = ({ acpt, rjct,item }) => {
      let content
    
      if (acpt) {
        content = <Text style={{ fontSize: 24, color: 'red' }}>Error</Text>
      } else if (rjct) {
        content = <Text style={{ fontSize: 24, color: 'gray' }}>Loading...</Text>
      } else {
        content = (
          <View>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 60 }}>{title}</Text>
          </View>
        )
      }
      
      return <View style={{ padding: 24 }}>{content}</View>
    }
    
    
    
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
         
                <FlatList
                    data={DATA}
      
                    keyExtractor= {item=> item.key}
                    contentContainerStyle={{
                        padding: 8,
             
                    }}
    
                    renderItem = {({item, index}) =>{
    
                        return <View style={[styles.FlatList,acpt||rjct ? styles.whiteFlatlist:''
      
                        ]}> 
                        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                             <Image
                                source={{uri: item.image}}
                                style={{width: AVATAR_SIZE, height: AVATAR_SIZE, borderRadius: AVATAR_SIZE, marginRight:SPACING/2}}
                            />
                            <View>
    
                                {[rjct ? <Text style={styles.declinemessage}> You have declined {item.fname}'s {"\n"} connection request. If you changed {"\n"} your mind, send them a connection {"\n"}request through their profile.
                                </Text>:[acpt? <Text style={styles.message}>{item.fname} is now your connection.{"\n"}Click to chat with them right now!</Text>: <Text style={styles.message}>{item.name} has sent you a {"\n"}connection request.</Text>]
                            
                            ]}</View>
                        </View>
                           
                                    <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
    
    
                                     <TouchableOpacity 
                                            style={[rjct ? styles.none :[acpt ? styles.bigButton : styles.buttonColorAccept]]}
                                            onPress={accept}>
    
                            <View>
                            {[acpt ? <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Find more connections like {item.fname}</Text>: [rjct? null:<Text style={styles.buttonText}>Accept</Text>]]}
                            </View>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                    
    
                                     <TouchableOpacity
                                            style={[rjct||acpt ?  styles.none :styles.buttonColorDecline ]}
                                            onPress={reject}
                                        >
                            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{[rjct||acpt ?  "" :"Decline" ] }</Text>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>
    
                        </View>
                        
                    }}
                />
    
            </View>
        )
    }
        
    
      
       
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        FlatList:{
            padding: 25, 
            marginBottom: 7, 
            backgroundColor:"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)", 
            borderRadius: 10,
            shadowColor:"0px 4px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)",
            shadowOffset:{
                width: 0,
                height: 10
            },
            shadowOpacity: .3,
            shadowRadius: 20,
        },
        button:{
            borderRadius: 20,
            // backgroundColor: "#ffad2f",
            width: 105,
            height: 32,
            shadowColor: "0px 4px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
            shadowOffset: {
                width: 0,
                height: 3,
            },
            shadowOpacity: 0.32,
            shadowRadius: 5.46,
    
            elevation: 9,
            // marginLeft:55
            marginTop:15
        },
                  none:{
                               
                  },
        buttonText:{
            fontWeight: "900",
            fontSize: 18,
            color: "#FFFFFF",
            width: "auto", /* 50px */
            height: "auto", /* 19px */
            overflow: "visible",
            fontFamily: "JosefinSans-Regular",
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            textAlign: 'center',
            marginTop:1
    
        },
        buttonColorAccept:{
            backgroundColor:"#ffad2f",
            marginLeft: 70,
            borderRadius: 20,
            // backgroundColor: "#ffad2f",
            width: 105,
            height: 32,
            shadowColor: "0px 4px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
            shadowOffset: {
                width: 0,
                height: 3,
            },
            shadowOpacity: 0.32,
            shadowRadius: 5.46,
    
            elevation: 9,
            // marginLeft:55
            marginTop:15
        },
        buttonColorDecline:
        {
            backgroundColor: "#e71d36",
            marginLeft: 15,
                  
            borderRadius: 20,
            // backgroundColor: "#ffad2f",
            width: 105,
            height: 32,
            shadowColor: "0px 4px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
            shadowOffset: {
                width: 0,
                height: 3,
            },
            shadowOpacity: 0.32,
            shadowRadius: 5.46,
    
            elevation: 9,
            // marginLeft:55
            marginTop:15
    
        },
        bigButton:{
             width:300,
            height:30,
            backgroundColor:"#ffad2f",
            borderRadius:25,   
            marginLeft:50, 
            shadowColor: "0px 4px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)",
            shadowOffset: {
                width: 0,
                height: 3,
    
            },
            shadowOpacity: 0.32,
            shadowRadius: 5.46,
            marginLeft:19,
            elevation: 9, 
            marginTop: 15,
    
            textAlign: 'center',
            // justifyContent: 'center'  
                               
        },
        message:
            {
                fontWeight: '900', 
                fontFamily:'JosefinSans-Regular',
                fontSize: 16,
                marginLeft: -5,
                width: 300,
                marginLeft:10,
                marginTop: 7, 
                lineHeight:21.5,
                // lineHeight:25,
                textAlign:"left",
                fontStyle:"normal",
            },
        declinemessage:{
                fontWeight: '900', 
                fontFamily:'JosefinSans-Regular',
                fontSize: 15,
                fontWeight:"900",
                marginLeft: 5,
                marginTop: 7, 
                lineHeight:20,
                textAlign:"left",
                fontStyle:"normal",
                letterSpacing: .05
        
        
        
        },
        whiteFlatlist:{
            backgroundColor:"#ffffff",
            padding: 25, 
            marginBottom: 7, 
            borderRadius: 10,
            shadowColor:"0px 4px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)",
            shadowOffset:{
                 width: 0,
                 height: 10
             },
            shadowOpacity: .3,
            shadowRadius: 20,
            elevation:9
        }
    
        
    });
```

Comment: It is very hard to understand what do you want. You should describe your problem. Also try to use smaller screenshots or don't use it at all

Comment: i have accept n decline button on flatlist if I press on accept then I want get access them individually but if u see this ss the all flatlist item is changing simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want each list item to have its on accept and reject variable. You have declared the accept and reject in the parent component of the FlatList.

I think you'd want to move these variables into the renderItem so that each item of the list has its own accept/reject state.

I'd also suggest you give your state setters a name that clearly states  its a setter.

```js
const [accept, setAccept] = useState(false)
// just from reading the variable names you know which is the setter

const [acpt, accept] = useState(false)
// here the naming is vague and finding the setter requires
// referencing the declaration
```